# Illegal characters in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a .NET application written in C# that saves information in XML format. The application serializes the application data into xml. The application contains a textbox where the user is free to enter any text. I have cases where users have managed to enter characters, mostly when they copy and paste text from other applications into the textbox, where the xml document becomes corrupted. Is there a general approach to manage illegal characters in xml documents without having to filter them out in every textbox on entry.

Sample from document thats corrupted

```
<Propery>
  <Name>&#x8;Alimentação Controlador</Name>
  <Value>24</Value>
  <Unit>Vca</Unit>
</Propery>
```

Document is serialized with ASCIIEncoding.UTF8

Comment: Which `encoding` does the XML document declare? How do you produce the XML (do you use an XML library, or do you generate it directly)?

Comment: In your case & is the problem.

Comment: Document declares <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: @FlorimMaxhuni No, the problem is the BS (Backspace, code 0x08) character, which is invalid in XML 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to "SafeEncode" the string entered by the user.  this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(VS.80).aspx shows you how to do it easily with one call to the SecurityElement.Escape(string s) method.

Comment: This will not help, as the problem is the &#x8; character, which will be left untouched by the SecurityElement.Escape method.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace following illegal characters with:

> `&lt;` (<)
>
> `&amp;` (&)
>
> `&gt;` (>)
>
> `&quot;` (")
>
> `&apos;` (')

Answer (score 0):

You may use even this "incriminated" characters if you wish using CDATA

[look here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You should use best practices as suggested by JTMon.

I also ran into same situation when exporting to XML. I dont know whether it would work for you or not but try using `stringbuilder` instead `string` to generate xml.

You can try this too

```
i.SubItems[0].Text.Trim('\0')
```

Hope it would help.